# Added module with Twitter-Bootstap 3 and now my menu disappeared.

Tags: module, joomla-3.3.x, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just made a 'custom html' module in my J3 website.

I made a custom Mail Chimp subscription form using Twitter Bootstrap 3 (linked in module).

below is the exact code from my module:

```
    <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
color:black;
text-align:center;
    }

    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div class="bs-example">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="//get2gethersports.us9.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=7c0d513e0a7edb9e73598c3d8&amp;id=dac19d65a1" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <h2>Join our mailing list!</h2>
        <p style="font-size:15px;">Sign up with your email address to receive the latest news and updates from get2gether|sports</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="mce-EMAIL">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email" name="EMAIL">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="mce-FNAME">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="First Name" name="FNAME">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="mce-LNAME">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="Last Name" name="LNAME">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscirbe</button>
<p style="font-size:12px;">We respect your privacy.</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

My website is http://get2gethersports.com

after adding the the code which looks spot on my menu disappeared...

Any ideas why? Maybe something with the linked bootstrap? Any solutions?

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Fixed it by switching verions. went from bootstrap 3.x to bootstrap 2.3.2 and it took way less code!

Comment: I clearly use too many bootstrap 3 based templates .  I removed my incorrect response.  Joomla's core being based in 2.3.2 is likely why it worked for you :)

Comment: @ToniMarie it sucks. I see a lot of templates using 2.3.2. when I really wanna be using 3.3.0. The worst part of switching was it did not collapse below 768px and their is no way to do that. So I did a crazy random media query from x to x setting a width rather... yuck.